# swift create a variable

Tags: swift, variables, swiftui

```
struct home : View {
    var dateFormatter: DateFormatter {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        return formatter
    }

    @State private var urlaubdate = Date()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            DatePicker(selection: $urlaubdate, in: Date()..., displayedComponents: .date) {
                Text("Select a date")
            }

            Text("Date is \(urlaubdate, formatter: dateFormatter)")
        }
    }
}
```

I have created this script and I want to ask how I can get the (**(urlaubdate, formatter: dateFormatter)**) into a variable below the code?

Comment: urlaubdate already contains the selected date content. Can you explain what variable you need?

Comment: I want it formatted

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO :) Could you edit the title so that it is a question? At the moment it is not very clear what you are asking

Answer (score 0):

Find below the code with variable containing the formatted date.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var dateFormatter: DateFormatter {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        return formatter
    }

    @State private var urlaubdate = Date()

    var body: some View {

        let newDate: String = dateFormatter.string(from: urlaubdate)

        return VStack {
            DatePicker(selection: $urlaubdate, in: Date()..., displayedComponents: .date) {
                Text("Select a date")
            }

            Text("Date is \(urlaubdate, formatter: dateFormatter)")
            Text(newDate)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: No worries :) SwiftUI is awesome.